# How do I get only the PID, without any extra information, of a process running on port 3000?

Tags: linux, shell-script, process, port

I'm using CentOS 7.  I want to get the PID (if one exists) of the process running on port 3000.  I would like to get this PID for the purposes of saving it to a variable in a shell script.  So far I have

```
[rails@server proddir]$ sudo ss -lptn 'sport = :3000'
State      Recv-Q Send-Q                           Local Address:Port                                          Peer Address:Port
Cannot open netlink socket: Protocol not supported
LISTEN     0      0                                            *:3000                                                     *:*                   users:(("ruby",pid=4861,fd=7),("ruby",pid=4857,fd=7),("ruby",pid=4855,fd=7),("ruby",pid=4851,fd=7),("ruby",pid=4843,fd=7))
```

but I can't figure out how to isolate the PID all by itself without all this extra information.

Comment: ``sudo ss -lptnH "sport = :22" | awk -F " " '{printf $6}' | sed 's/.\+pid=\([0-9]\+\).\+/\1/g'``. Do you need explanation?

Comment: No explanation needed but this results in a "ss: invalid option -- 'H'" error.

Comment: You probably have an old ``ss`` without of this option. Should work even without of it: ``sudo ss -lptn "sport = :22" | awk -F " " '{printf $6}' | sed 's/.\+pid=\([0-9]\+\).\+/\1/g'
``

Comment: @user996142 not a very helpful comment. might be a good answer though

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
lsof -t -i :<port> -s <PROTO>:LISTEN
```

For example:

```
# lsof -i :22 -s TCP:LISTEN
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd    1392 root    3u  IPv4  19944      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd    1392 root    4u  IPv6  19946      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
# lsof -t -i :22 -s TCP:LISTEN
1392
```

Comment: Tried "lsof -t -i :3000 TCP:LISTEN" and got the error, "lsof: status error on TCP:LISTEN: No such file or directory"

Comment: @Dave Run it without `TCP:LISTEN`.

Comment: @Dave I've miss `-s` key. I've fix it in pattern. An example had this key.

Comment: Right tool for the job.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
pid=$(fuser 3000/tcp 2>/dev/null)
```

(requires `psmisc` package)

Please note, that this is reliable only when run by the user root. Others user can only hope to find processes running with the same user.

---

Boring explanation for root only access with an example here.
Whatever the method used (fuser, ss, lsof, ...) they all end up matching the available list of process' descriptors to an available list of network connections (eg for tcp it's available in `/proc/net/tcp`).
For example, trying to get the pid using port `22/tcp` (with 22 = 0x0016) would end up doing this kind of comparison:

Entry from `/proc/net/tcp`:
`0: 00000000:0016 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 141408 1 000000000a9ac1b5 100 0 0 10 0`

with:
`dr-x------. 2 root root 0 May 14 17:59 /proc/358/fd
lrwx------. 1 root root 64 May 14   17:59 /proc/358/fd/3 -> socket:[141408]`

As this fd descriptor is only available for its user (which happen to be root in this example) or root, only that user or root can find out the pid is 358.

Answer (score 5):

While `lsof`'s `-t` is the simplest way to get the PID, `lsof` also has ways to select other fields using the `-F` option:

```
$ lsof -F'?'
lsof:   ID    field description
     a    access: r = read; w = write; u = read/write
     c    command name
     d    device character code
     D    major/minor device number as 0x<hex>
     f    file descriptor (always selected)
     G    file flaGs
     i    inode number
     k    link count
     K    task ID (TID)
     l    lock: r/R = read; w/W = write; u = read/write
     L    login name
     m    marker between repeated output
     n    comment, name, Internet addresses
     o    file offset as 0t<dec> or 0x<hex>
     p    process ID (PID)
     g    process group ID (PGID)
     P    protocol name
     r    raw device number as 0x<hex>
     R    paRent PID
     s    file size
     S    stream module and device names
     t    file type
     T    TCP/TPI info
     u    user ID (UID)
     0    (zero) use NUL field terminator instead of NL
```

With output like so (note that PID and file descriptors are always printed):

```
$ sudo lsof -F cg -i :22 -s TCP:LISTEN 
p901
g901
csshd
f3
f4
```

So if you wanted the process group ID instead of the PID, you could do:

```
$ sudo lsof -F g -i :22 -s TCP:LISTEN | awk '/^g/{print substr($0, 2)}'
901
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need exactly

```
sudo lsof -n -i :3000  | awk '/LISTEN/{print $2}'
12726
12730
12732
```

Answer (score 1):

*Caveat: I can only test this on RedHat.*

Should be possible with `netstat`?

```
 sudo netstat -npl --inet | awk '/:3000/' | awk -F "[ /]+" '{print $7}'
```

**-n** for numeric ports
**-l** for listening ports
**-p** to see PIDs

You can use *--inet* or *--inet6* switches to tell `netstat` to only look 
for IPv4 or IPv6 respectively, otherwise you might get two results.

Alternatively you can tell `awk` to print only once

```
sudo netstat -npl | awk '/:3000/' | awk -F "[ /]+" '{print $7; exit}'
```

In `awk` we just use the '**/**' from `netstat`'s output of PID/program as a separator.